# Apply division calc to only one segment of query

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below query runs a division calculation based on an Inner Join.

I would like to modify this query so that the division calc (q1.a/q2.d) only runs on the last date ('17_Q4), and the rest of the dates (17_Q1...17_Q3) returns just q1.a (i.e., no division calc).

```
Select qqyy, q1.b, q1.a/q2.d as result from(
with q(qqyy, firstday, lastday) as (
  select '17_Q1', DATE '2016-01-30', DATE '2016-04-30' union all
  select '17_Q2', DATE '2016-04-30', DATE '2016-07-30' union all
  select '17_Q3', DATE '2016-07-30', DATE '2016-10-29' union all
  select '17_Q4', DATE '2016-10-29', DATE '2016-10-29' + 45
)
SELECT q.qqyy, cobrand_id b, sum(calc) a
from temp_08.jwn_calc s
join q on
s.optimized_transaction_date > q.firstday
and s.optimized_transaction_date <= q.lastday
GROUP BY q.qqyy, cobrand_id ) q1

Inner join (
select cobrand_id c,
      Sum(case when optimized_transaction_date > '2015-10-31'
and optimized_transaction_date <= '2015-10-31' + 45 then Calc end) / 
Sum(case when optimized_transaction_date > '2015-10-31' 
and optimized_transaction_date <= '2015-10-31' + 91 then Calc end) d
from temp_08.jwn_calc
GROUP BY cobrand_id) q2 on q1.b = q2.c
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the sample data can be simplified using a `values` clause inside the CTE. The lengthy `union all` is not necessary (and you don't really need the `with at all there - `from (values ('17_Q1', DATE '2016-01-30', DATE '2016-04-30'), (...), ... ) as q(qqyy, firstday, lastday)` will do just fine

Comment: Also: please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I simply want to select q1.a for '17_Q1', '17_Q2', '17_Q3' and q1.a/q2.d for '17_Q4'.  In other words, perform the division calc for only '17_Q4'.  I can provide data but hopefully it's not needed.